# PasteSpecial xlPasteValues leaving only 2 decimals

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA Macro which copies a range (formulas resulting in numbers) from one workbook, creates a new excel file and pastes data (as values) in the new workbook:

```
    Selection.Copy
 
    Set TempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
      .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    End With
```

Unfortunately, in the new workbook values are stored as only 2-decimal numbers. Is there a way to paste values without losing the other decimals?

Comment: So did you set formatting to limit 2 decimals? As new sheets tend to show all decimals unless you change that.

Comment: You're right. If I try copying from another workbook, after pasting all decimals are kept. But with this specific file, they are not. Formatting in the original file doesn't change the behaviour (even if I show 10 decimals, only 2 are kept)

Comment: I figured it out: it wasn't the copy and paste, but the subsequent saving as csv (I had to change the formatting before saving)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Or you can have your destination cell already formated to match the original format.

Comment: I tried both and it shows many decimals, but all decimals after the second are zeros (so 1.2495868 becomes 1.2400000). The problem anyway looks specific with this file (please see my answer to Mike's comment)

Comment: Hard to say what might be causing this beahaviour with this specific file. Have you debug in a way that allows you to understand what the contents of selection copy are?